# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, utf-8

В текстовом поле пишется на русском, а в посте появляется это "Р СѓСЃСЃРєРёР№".
Везде на сайте если написать по-русски, выводит символы

Везде прописана кодировка utf8... Что делать?

Comment: Все шаблоны и файла в нужной кодировке? Что из себя представляет сайт?

Comment: клон твиттера

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите что бы

1. Все файлы (вида 'те что выводят
       данные') были в одной кодировке
2. Посмотрите что прописано в заголовке
       html документа не посредственно в
       браузере
3. Посмотрите в какой кодировке отдает
       База Данных записи
4. И самое редкое в какой кодировке
       отдает сервер

добавь в htacsses AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: везде во всех 4 utf8

Comment: вы переносили БД?

Comment: гляньте в каком виде текст в бд

Comment: может там не посредственно крокозяблы записаны.

Comment: текст отображается на русском в базе данныых

Comment: сайт на денвере

Comment: СПАСИБО, ДОБАВИЛ в htacsses AddDefaultCharset UTF-8, до этого лазил не в тот htacsses

Comment: пропиши теперь кодировку в настройках Денвера

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у Вас сохраняется в кодировке UTF-8 without BOM. У меня как-то похожая проблема.

Answer (score 0):

*Решение под PHP.* В свое время остановился на отправке хэдера с нужной кодировкой:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Однако из вопроса не совсем понятно, на каком уровне проблема. Имеется в виду, что пользователь пишет твит по-русски, а публикуется он черт знает как? Очень похоже, что дело в кодировке БД. Возможно, стоит дополнительно явно указывать кодировку при выполнении SQL-запроса.